# Transaction rejected anytime I try to interact with a smart contract, what is wrong?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

it seems like a very simple contract, but everytime I tried to send some ETH to the smart contract, it says transaction rejected. I did include '''address payable''' in the code, so what is wrong?

'''

```
pragma solidity 0.5.17;

contract Bet {

uint256 public betSum;
address payable public owner;

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;     
}



function checkSum() public view returns (uint256) {
    return betSum;
}


function withdrawEther(uint256 amount) external payable onlyOwner {
require(address(this).balance>=amount, 'Error, contract has 
 insufficent balance');
owner.transfer(amount);

}
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending a value along with the transaction that deploys your contract, you'll need to make the constructor `payable`:

```
constructor() payable public {
    owner = msg.sender;     
}
```

If you want to send ETH to the contract at a later time, you'll need a way to receive it, either in a named deposit function, or in a [Fallback Function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#fallback-function).

You're using a relatively old Solidity version. If you move to a more recent version you could use a [Receive Ether Function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#receive-ether-function).

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, what do you think `owner == msg.sender;` does?

What it does, a comparison. The result of it is `false` and discarded anyway.

What do you need to do? Change that to `owner = msg.sender;`, an assignment.

Comment: I changed it, but it still does not work Xavier